# "this" not being recognized inside a function

Tags: function, typescript

I have a property defined but when I try to access it from inside a setInterval anonymous function, it is not being recognized.

```
  this.game.seconds = 6;
  useTimer() {
    let timer = setInterval(
      function () {
        this.game.seconds--;//here the keyword this is not being recognized
      }, 1000
    );
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Hint: it is because you are **not** using arrow function

Comment: This has nothing to do with TypeScript. The language you are programming in is called "JavaScript". TypeScript is merely a thin typing layer on top of JavaScript. TypeScript introduces no new semantics for `this`; indeed, it introduces no new execution semantics whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because you are not *not* using an Arrow Function.

Arrow functions take `this` from their outer execution context.

The [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) mentions:

> arrow functions which do provide their own this binding (it remains
>   the this value of the enclosing lexical context).

Read more in [No Binding of `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this).

So just to this instead:

```
let timer = setInterval(
  () => {
    this.game.seconds--; // 'this' takes its value from the outer context
  }, 1000
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I could fulfill my goal with arrow functions as commented by Dummy and answered by gsamaras:

```
  this.game.seconds = 6;
  useTimer() {
    let timer = setInterval(
      () => {
        this.game.seconds--;
      }, 1000
    );
  }
```

more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this).